# Is it possible to refer to function or object from particular script tag in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine we have the following code in an HTML file:

```
<script id='tag-1'>
  function foo(){
    alert("this is foo-1");
  }
</script>

<script id='tag-2'>
  function foo(){
    alert("this is foo-2");
  }
</script>

<script id='tag-3'>
  function foo(){
    alert("this is foo-3");
  }
</script>
```

Is it possible to invoke function `foo` from the script tag with id `tag-2`?
I'm just curious to know if there is any cross-browser solution? Thank's guys.

---

Ok we have two very relevant proposals -  the one that I marked for accepted answer and another one of the comments rigth below this post - the one that @dfsq propose. Thank you all guys!!!

Comment: You're trying to use <script> tag as a namespace and I don't think that would ever work. The question itself is curious ;)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Why not just name them `foo1()`, `foo2()` ...

Comment: how this question is getting votes ?

Comment: I'm curious what lead to this question. Are you actually trying to solve a problem that someone might know a different solution for or is this really nothing more than asking whether functions are still stored somewhere after being overloaded. The answer is yes, but only as string afaik, and you can eval that if you want.

Comment: @Nomi: The question is clear, specific and answerable, which makes it a good question. It does reveal that the OP isn't aware of how JavaScript namespaces work, but that's okay - if we all knew everything, then we wouldn't need a Q&A site in the first place.

Comment: @RenéGeuze I'd rather use the `Function` constructor in this case.

Comment: @Derija I didn't specifically mean the eval function in JavaScript, just a general approach to turn the string you get into usable code. I  don't think there is even 1 valid use case tho.

Comment: You can't unless you use some sort of eval: http://jsfiddle.net/X6s4F/

Comment: @Reinmar @RenéGeuze Because in this case, the OP has the string of a function available through the script tags with IDs. Trimming away the `function foo() { ... }` wouldn't even require a regular expression. Using the `Function` constructor, you'd get the exact same results as using `eval` and you could still assign it to a variable for later use. You can do the same with `eval`, it would just require "restructuring" the function name... The `Function` constructor probably uses `eval` behind the scenes anyways, I just think it looks... not as evil. ;) My preference. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is totally possible, but you should use a type other than text/javascript.

```
<script id='tag-1' type="myScriptHolder">
  function foo(){
    alert("this is foo-1");
  }
</script>

<script id='tag-2' type="myScriptHolder">
  function foo(){
    alert("this is foo-2");
  }
</script>

<script id='tag-3' type="myScriptHolder">
  function foo(){
    alert("this is foo-3");
  }
</script>

<script>
$.globalEval($('#tag-1').text();
</script>
```

Comment: Assuming that the OP only ever wanted to use one of the scripts for a given HTTP request, this would work. Otherwise, avoid this!!

Comment: Why do you say that? He could call $.globalEval($('#tag-xxx').text() several times in a row (but it would be up to him/her to avoid conflicts).

Comment: I said that given his example of using a function with the same name. But you're right that if there were no naming conflicts, or if overriding the function was intended, then this method would work well.

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not possible without resorting to `eval()`.

As each script block is evaluated by the browser the previous versions of the function are overwritten.

You *can* access the text context of each `<script>` tag, but only if it's inline.   Accessing the source of `<script src="...">` tags requires AJAX.

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU not much different to loading the files using AJAX and then interpreting them though.  The point still stands that as soon as the functions are loaded into the JS interpreter the other versions will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible. All Javascript code in the same window shares the same namespace, so what you're doing in your example is simply overriding `foo`, meaning that in the end you only have "foo-3".

iframes each have their own namespace but it wouldn't make sense to use iframes for something like this.

If the functions are only needed by their corresponding scripts, then you could wrap each script in a self-executing function, e.g.

```
(function() {
  function foo(){
    alert("this is foo-1");
  }
})();
```

This would mean that `foo` would be inaccessible from outside that script, which obviously may or may not work for you depending on where the function is used.

The only other alternative would be to create your own namespaces for the functions, e.g.:

```
var namespace1 = {};
namespace1.foo = function foo() {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have function overloading. Every next declaration with the same name(variable or function) just re-declares it with new value provided. So in your case function from tag-3 will always be executed.

Possible solution to what you want is
1. Give different names for each function.
or
2. If you are expecting functions to be called differently depending on arguments provided. You can check the implicit arguments object inside the function and do necessary operations depending upon that.

Simple example of the second solution can be given as follows.

```
function foo(bar){
    if(typeof bar==="number"){
         //Do number specific stuff here
    } else if(typeof bar==="string"){
        //Do string specific stuff here
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a javascript namespacing technique that is fairly common. This creates a new javascript object that is available, and you can reference via calls to  CodeGuru.File1.Foo();

```
var CodeGuru = CodeGuru || {};  
var CodeGuru.File1 = CodeGuru.File1 || {};
(function(CodeGuru) {
    CodeGuru.File1.Foo = function() {
        //insert code
    }
 })(CodeGuru);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
if (typeof (GenLib) == "undefined") GenLib = {};

    GenLib.Tag1 = {};
    GenLib.Tag2 = {};
    GenLib.Tag3= {};

    GenLib.Tag1.Foo = function () {
        alert("this is foo-1");
    };

    GenLib.Tag2.Foo = function () {
        alert("this is foo-2");
    };

    GenLib.Tag3.Foo = function () {
        alert("this is foo-3");
    };

    var theOneYouWantNow = GenLib.Tag2; // Or Tag1 or Tag3, use if/switch/whatever here.

    theOneYouWantNow.Foo();
```

Comment: This is fine solution, but I want to nest a JavaScript tools inside several HTML tags. Each tag will have its utilities whose will serve the tag. I want to treat these tags the same way so I need identical "interface". Namespaces will force me to map particular JavaScript object to each tag which I wish to avoid.